# Blue Prism Collection Loop to an Object

Tags: blueprism

Without creating a work queue, in a process is there a way to action line items from a collection one by one (possible loop)?

Scenario is from a business object, call to a collection, retrieve the name of the first item from a collection, action item in the business object, move to next line of the collection, action second item in the collection, repeat until the collection is complete.  Any way to do this without pulling it into the control room as a queue item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Loop stage (highlighted here):

[image: Loop stage]

Lay out your process something like this:

[image: Process layout with loop]

and configure its start stage to loop over the collection that contains your data:

[image: Loop stage configuration]

Once inside the loop, Blue Prism will keep track of the current row and allow you to reference the values from each field just by referencing the field in dot notation:

[image: Dot notation usage configuration]