# reset a counter in every iteraion of a loop

Tags: loops, counter, reset, blueprism

I'm a new user of blueprism.

I'm using two loops in blueprism and using a increment a counter. After finishing one loop and going to another, I need to reset the counter value. Please help me in doing that.

Comment: kindly go through that:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969142/blue-prism-collection-loop-to-an-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969142/blue-prism-collection-loop-to-an-object) Hope it helps

Comment: Simply use a calculation stage between the end of the first loop and the end of the second loop to reset the counter?

Comment: Use calculation stage and assign 0 to the counter variable before starting next loop

Answer (score 2):

Begin your loop, do your stuff in here and increment.

And right after the loop put a Calculation Stage and just save "0" to your incremented data item (the "reset" calc stage on the screenshot)

[image]